# Linear time Graph algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph, shortest-path, breadth-first-search, depth-first-search

Given an undirected graphG = (V,E), is there an algorithm that computes the total number of shortest path between two arbitrary vertices u & v ? I think we can make use of the Dijkstra's algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use dijkstra. Create an array that store total number of shortest path to any node. Call it total. Initial value of all array member is 0 except total[s] = 1 where s is source.

In dijkstra loop, when comparing smallest path of a node, if the result of comparation is smaller, update the total array of that node with the number of total of current node. if it equals, add the total array of that node with the number of total of current node.

Pseudocode taken from wikipedia with some modification:

```
function Dijkstra(Graph, source):

  create vertex set Q

  for each vertex v in Graph:             // Initialization
      dist[v] ← INFINITY                  // Unknown distance from source to v
      total[v] ← 0                        // total number of shortest path
      add v to Q                          // All nodes initially in Q (unvisited nodes)

  dist[source] ← 0                        // Distance from source to source
  total[source] ← 1                       // total number of shortest path of source is set to 1

  while Q is not empty:
      u ← vertex in Q with min dist[u]    // Source node will be selected first
      remove u from Q 

      for each neighbor v of u:           // where v is still in Q.
          alt ← dist[u] + length(u, v)
          if alt < dist[v]:               // A shorter path to v has been found
              dist[v] ← alt 
              total[v] ← total[u]         // update the total array of that node with the number of total array of current node
          elseif alt = dist[v]
              total[v] ← total[v] + total[u] // add the total array of that node with the number of total array of current node

  return dist[], total[]
```

Comment: Dijkstra's by itself won't give the shortest paths count between *any* two arbitrary vertices, just between the one vertex you ran it on and any other.

Comment: Yes, it's beacuse Dijkstra is Single Souce Shortest Path algorithm. But I think the question is about the total number of finding shortest path between two arbitrary vertices u & v, without any.

If it is intended to "any two vertex", floyd-warshall algorithm can be used with some modification. And it's not linear.

Comment: what is the running time of the above algorithm?

Comment: Time complexity of floyd warshall algorithm is O(V^3)